Difference in Standard Errors and p-Values in Two-Way Fixed Effects Logit Model with Interaction Terms using fixest Package in R
I'm working with a two-way fixed effects (TWFE) logit model in R using the fixest package. My model includes interaction terms between some fixed effects and a categorical variable called group. To report the coefficients of each fixed effect term, I've included one of the fixed effects as a regular control variable. However, I've noticed that this approach leads to differences in standard errors and p-values compared to the standard TWFE model.
When I include one of the fixed effects (e.g., wave) as a regular control variable instead of as a fixed effect, the standard errors and p-values differ, although the coefficients remain the same. Below is a reproducible example:

  library(fixest)
library(dplyr)

# Simulate data
set.seed(12345)
n <- 1000  
data <- data.frame(
  outcome = rbinom(n, 1, 0.5),
  group = factor(sample(c("Group1", "Group2", "Group3"), n, replace = TRUE)),
  event1 = rbinom(n, 1, 0.3),
  event2 = rbinom(n, 1, 0.2),
  event3 = rbinom(n, 1, 0.4),
  event4 = rbinom(n, 1, 0.25),
  age_group = factor(sample(2:4, n, replace = TRUE)),
  gender = factor(sample(c("Male", "Female"), n, replace = TRUE)),
  education = factor(sample(c("Low", "Medium", "High"), n, replace = TRUE)),
  ethnicity = factor(sample(c("Ethnic1", "Ethnic2"), n, replace = TRUE)),
  income_level = factor(sample(1:4, n, replace = TRUE)),
  perception = factor(sample(1:3, n, replace = TRUE)),
  previous_vote = rbinom(n, 1, 0.4),
  struggle = factor(sample(1:3, n, replace = TRUE)),
  news_type = factor(sample(c("News1", "News2", "News3", "NoNews"), n, replace = TRUE)),
  location_type = factor(sample(c("Urban", "Rural"), n, replace = TRUE)),
  city = factor(sample(1:10, n, replace = TRUE)),
  wave = factor(sample(paste0("Wave", 1:5), n, replace = TRUE)),
  weight = runif(n, 0.5, 2)
)

# Model 1: Including Wave as a fixed effect
model1 <- feglm(
  outcome ~ i(group, "Group1") + 
    i(group, event1, ref = "Group1", ref2 = "0") + 
    i(group, event2, ref = "Group1", ref2 = "0") + 
    i(group, event3, ref = "Group1", ref2 = "0") + 
    i(group, event4, ref = "Group1", ref2 = "0") + 
    i(age_group, ref = "2") + gender + education + 
    i(ethnicity, ref = "Ethnic1") + income_level + 
    i(perception, ref = "2") + as.factor(previous_vote) + 
    i(struggle, ref = "2") + as.factor(news_type) + location_type | city + wave,
  data = data, 
  family = binomial("logit"), 
  weights = data$weight,
  cluster = ~city + wave
)

summary(model1, vcov = "twoway", ssc = ssc(adj = FALSE, cluster.adj = FALSE))

# Model 2: Including Wave as a regular control variable
model2 <- feglm(
  outcome ~ i(group, "Group1") + i(wave, ref = "Wave5") + 
    i(group, event1, ref = "Group1", ref2 = "0") + 
    i(group, event2, ref = "Group1", ref2 = "0") + 
    i(group, event3, ref = "Group1", ref2 = "0") + 
    i(group, event4, ref = "Group1", ref2 = "0") + 
    i(age_group, ref = "2") + gender + education + 
    i(ethnicity, ref = "Ethnic1") + income_level + 
    i(perception, ref = "2") + as.factor(previous_vote) + 
    i(struggle, ref = "2") + as.factor(news_type) + location_type | city,
  data = data, 
  family = binomial("logit"), 
  weights = data$weight,
  cluster = ~city + wave
)

summary(model2, vcov = "twoway", ssc = ssc(adj = FALSE, cluster.adj = FALSE))


Questions:

Is the difference in standard errors and p-values between the two models due to the adjustment of degrees of freedom?

Is this a statistical problem (e.g. incidental parameter problem) or purely a software issue? If just a software issue, how can I fix it?



Please add any user-contributed packages in your R code. Eg. library(fixest).
